# How to change the position of character counter in maxLength function in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

![enter image description here][1]I am using **jquery.maxlength-min.js** to place a character counter for a text box. 
The character counter div tags for the text box comes at the bottom of the text box by default when the jquery is running.
Becasue of that a label next to the text box has changed it's position.
How should I edit the jquery.maxlength-min.js to get it on top of the text box ?
Following is the HTML

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maxlength-min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#textarea_1_1').maxlength(); 
      });

    </script>
      </head>
    <body>  
      <input type="text" id="textarea_1_1"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Following are the .js files I am using.

**jquery.maxlength-min.js**

```
/**
 * jQuery Maxlength plugin
 * @version     $Id: jquery.maxlength.js 18 2009-05-16 15:37:08Z emil@anon-design.se $
 * @package     jQuery maxlength 1.0.5
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2009 Emil Stjerneman / http://www.anon-design.se
 * @license     GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.txt
 */
 (function(A){A.fn.maxlength=function(B){var C=jQuery.extend({events:[],maxCharacters:30,status:true,statusClass:"status",statusText:"character right",notificationClass:"notification",showAlert:false,alertText:"You have typed too many characters.",slider:false},B);A.merge(C.events,["keyup"]);return this.each(function(){var G=A(this);var J=A(this).val().length;function D(){var K=C.maxCharacters-J;if(K<0){K=0}G.next("div").html(K+" "+C.statusText)}function E(){var K=true;if(J>=C.maxCharacters){K=false;G.addClass(C.notificationClass);G.val(G.val().substr(0,C.maxCharacters));I()}else{if(G.hasClass(C.notificationClass)){G.removeClass(C.notificationClass)}}if(C.status){D()}}function I(){if(C.showAlert){alert(C.alertText)}}function F(){var K=false;if(G.is("textarea")){K=true}else{if(G.filter("input[type=text]")){K=true}else{if(G.filter("input[type=password]")){K=true}}}return K}if(!F()){return false}A.each(C.events,function(K,L){G.bind(L,function(M){J=G.val().length;E()})});if(C.status){G.after(A("<div/>").addClass(C.statusClass).html("-"));D()}if(!C.status){var H=G.next("div."+C.statusClass);if(H){H.remove()}}if(C.slider){G.next().hide();G.focus(function(){G.next().slideDown("fast")});G.blur(function(){G.next().slideUp("fast")})}})}})(jQuery);
```

Other than that I am using **jquery-1.3.2.min.js**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified version of jquery.maxlength.min.js below will put the counter above your `textarea`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk3ttbc3/)

`(function(A) {
    A.fn.maxlength = function(B) {
        var C = jQuery.extend({events: [], maxCharacters: 30, status: true, statusClass: "status", statusText: "character right", notificationClass: "notification", showAlert: false, alertText: "You have typed too many characters.", slider: false}, B);
        A.merge(C.events, ["keyup"]);
        return this.each(function() {
            var G = A(this);
            var J = A(this).val().length;
            function D() {
                var K = C.maxCharacters - J;
                if (K < 0) {
                    K = 0
                }
                G.prev("div").html(K + " " + C.statusText)
            }
            function E() {
                var K = true;
                if (J >= C.maxCharacters) {
                    K = false;
                    G.addClass(C.notificationClass);
                    G.val(G.val().substr(0, C.maxCharacters));
                    I()
                } else {
                    if (G.hasClass(C.notificationClass)) {
                        G.removeClass(C.notificationClass)
                    }
                }
                if (C.status) {
                    D()
                }
            }
            function I() {
                if (C.showAlert) {
                    alert(C.alertText)
                }
            }
            function F() {
                var K = false;
                if (G.is("textarea")) {
                    K = true
                } else {
                    if (G.filter("input[type=text]")) {
                        K = true
                    } else {
                        if (G.filter("input[type=password]")) {
                            K = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                return K
            }
            if (!F()) {
                return false
            }
            A.each(C.events, function(K, L) {
                G.bind(L, function(M) {
                    J = G.val().length;
                    E()
                })
            });
            if (C.status) {
                G.before(A("").addClass(C.statusClass).html("-"));
                D()
            }
            if (!C.status) {
                var H = G.prev("div." + C.statusClass);
                if (H) {
                    H.remove()
                }
            }
            if (C.slider) {
                G.prev().hide();
                G.focus(function() {
                    G.prev().slideDown("fast")
                });
                G.blur(function() {
                    G.prev().slideUp("fast")
                })
            }
        })
    }
})(jQuery);`

Comment: Did you try the JS Fiddle?

Comment: yes. It is working for $('#textarea_1_1').maxlength();  without  giving a feedback target. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need create an element wherever you want and target that element in your maxlength plugin call:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#textarea_1_1').maxlength({
            'feedbackTarget' : '#yourElementId'
        }); 
      });
</script>
```

http://keith-wood.name/maxlengthRef.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: still it do not change the behavior. Should I add showFeedBack to true? I added it as follows. but not working.                       $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#textarea_1_1').maxlength({
            'feedbackTarget' : '#yourElementId'
        }); 
      });

Comment: It do not set to the feedback target. it dynamically creates a div down after the text box